# Why Mail is receiving in Spam?

Tags: php

I have the following code which sent the mail as spam .Please help me how to receive main not as spam

```
     <?php 


    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $to = "narayan_alz@hotmail.com";
   $subject = "This is a Registration Message For Plasma Seminar";
    $message = "Title=$title    First Name=$fname    Last Name=$lname ";
  $header = "from:$email";
   $retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

?>
```

Comment: Try making it look less like spam?

Answer (score 2):

Its not the code, its the server,

Whitelist your ip at http://www.spamhaus.org/ and other similar sites.

Lookup for your ip here, http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/

Answer (score 1):

Your email is not sent as spam, but the spam filter that hotmail uses registers your email as spam. There is no way to prevent this from your PHP code apart from making emails that people don't flag as spam.

What you can do in hotmail is add the sender email address to your address book (recommended) or disable the spam filter (not recommended)

Comment: It is not the matter of Hotmail in other mail also it is receiving as spam.I want solve it out .how??

Answer (score 1):

Getting your mail NOT marked as spam is an art itself. You'll probably want to check the following:

1) Make sure your mail server is not an open relay.

2) Make sure reverse DNS and PTR records are correct. If this is wrong, there is already a big chance your mail will be marked as spam.

3) Implement Sender Policy Framework (SPF)

4) Implement DKIM

make sure the hostname listed in the SMTP HELO banner matches your hostname

Comment: Is there any code to prevent mail being as spam in my above code

Comment: Those are not related to code issues, these are pure mail server configuration issues. I advice you spent some time researching to set up your mail server correctly, or find someone who can do it for you. Another option is to use a hosted service like MailJet, MailChimp or SendGrid

Answer (score 0):

In this case (hotmail) you'll need to apply to get your server IP address white listed.

https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts&scrx=1